# Problems getting HelloWorld for Mule to work

Tags: eclipse, mule

I'm trying out the example Hello World from this link here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2INTRO/Quick+Start

I have the MuleIDE installed and I'm on the "Create a Mule Application" section.  I'm following it, but at the end when Mule IDE generates the project, there is no conf directory with the hello-config.xml file.  Where have I gone wrong?  Any ideas?  My created project looks like this below.  Thanks :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong: your project is A-OK.

The configuration file(s) are in src/main/app and will end-up at the root of the generated application archive.

Answer (score 0):

your .xml file will be present inside src/main/app drop-down menu...it's the one where all ur flows will be created and saved :)